# Which param attribute for: method throws an exception if arg1 is null?

Tags: c#

There is a parameter attribute `DoesNotReturnIf` (bool) which indicates that a method won't return if the bool param is equal to the specified value in `DoesNotReturnIf`.

But what if the method throws an exception if a param is null? (which is much more useful)

Something like `DoesNotReturnIfNull`. But it seems not to exist. Resharper handles this with:

```
[ContractAnnotation("arg: null => halt")]
public static void NotNull([NoEnumeration] object? arg, [InvokerParameterName] string argName, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = "")
{
    if (arg == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(argName, callerName);
}
```

Comment: No such attribute.  You need to move the throw statement into a separate static method.  Important, methods containing `throw` cannot be inlined.  Now you can annotate it with [DoesNotReturn].

Comment: No such thing as @HansPassant said, but you might be interested by [the package Guard Clauses](https://github.com/ardalis/GuardClauses). It provides a convenient way to write guard clauses in C#